# How to set a custom id for listitems in BulletedList control while binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

I am binding a BulletedList control in page load to a datasource, what i want to do is to set custom IDs for this BulletedList's ListItems while binding
This custom ID will be in my current case `"li_"+ItemId.ToString()`

Sample Code i used to fill the bulletedList:

```
bulletedList.DataSource = MyDataCollection;
bulletedList.DataTextField = "Name";
bulletedList.DataValueField = "Id";
bulletedList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand now...

you mean like this?:

```
 private void BindBulletList()
     {
         List<string> list = new List<string>();
         list.Add("item1");
         list.Add("item2");
         list.Add("item3");
         list.Add("item4");
         list.Add("item5");

         bullets.DataSource = list;
         bullets.DataBind();

         foreach (ListItem item in bullets.Items)
         {
             item.Attributes.Add("Id", "li_" + item.Text);
         }


     }
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

use linq:

var list = MyDataCollection.Select(x => new {Name = x.Name, Id = "li_"+ x.Id});

then bind list to bulletedlist as you have.

Comment: this did nothing to my li ids, it gave me the same result as my code, do i need to bind it in a special way after that?

Comment: Did you change the datasource, eg:

bulletedList.DataSource = list;

Comment: Yes i did, and nothing new happened, i can't imagine how this code can edit the ID attribute of the ListItem